# ENTITY/LINQ/ASP.NET : ASPxGridView Adding Rules

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am working on a small project which uses Entity Framework and I am currently learning about ASPxGridView, however, I cannot seem to find anything on the internet which relates to adding rules to columns which then shows either an icon or highlights the row depending on the rules set.

Something like this: https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Rows/ConditionalFormatting.aspx

If anyone could send me any references that they can find that may help point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want an icon that should be quite straightforwards, you want a template so you can put in the logic to show the icon. Have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb288032.aspx. Coloring the cell background may be more tricky since you don't control the the td element markup. You might be better with a Repeater or ListView for that as it gives you more control over markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Front end to add on the Entity Framework ASPxGridView Model:**

```
OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared"
```

**Back end to add:**

```
// Add this in the Namespace area, not inside the Page_Load function
public bool ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer { get; set; }

protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender,
DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
{
    // if statements go here
    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
}
```

**Code result:**

All **Cell** background colors change to `LightCyan`

**References:**

[ASPxGridView.HtmlRowPrepared Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_HtmlRowPreparedtopic) 
[TreeListSettingsBehavior.ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListTreeListSettingsBehavior_ProcessSelectionChangedOnServertopic)